# SQL Data to interpolate/extrapolate

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

If i have a table that keeps a running average of kW usage at a certain temperature, and I wanted to get a kW usage for a temperature that has not been recorded before, how could i get either

**(A)** Two data points above or two points below the temperature to extrapolate.

**(B)** Closest data above and below the temperature to interpolate

The table **temperatures** looks like this

```
         Column          |       Type       | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target |  Description
-------------------------+------------------+-----------+---------+--------------+---------------
 temperature_io_id       | integer          | not null  | plain   |              |
 temperature_station_id  | integer          | not null  | plain   |              |
 temperature_value       | integer          | not null  | plain   |              | in Fahrenheit
 temperature_current_kw  | double precision | not null  | plain   |              |
 temperature_value_added | integer          | default 1 | plain   |              |
 temperature_kw_year_1   | double precision | default 0 | plain   |              |

"temperatures_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (temperature_io_id, temperature_station_id, temperature_value)
```

**(A)** Proposed Solution

This would be a bit easier I think. The query would order the rows by the temperature value `>` or `<` the temperature im going for, then limit the results to 2? This would give me the two closest values that are above or below the temperature. Of course the order would have to be descending and ascending to make sure i get the right side of the items.

```
SELECT * FROM temperatures
WHERE
temperature_value > ACTUALTEMP and temperature_io_id = ACTUAL_IO_id
ORDER BY
temperature_value
LIMIT 2;
```

I think similar to above, but just limit it to 1 and do 2 queries, one for `>` and the other for `<`. I feel like this could be done better though?

Edit - Some sample data

```
 temperature_io_id | temperature_station_id | temperature_value | temperature_current_kw | temperature_value_added | temperature_kw_year_1
-------------------+------------------------+-------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------
             18751 |                    151 |                35 |                   26.1 |                       2 |                     0
             18752 |                    151 |                35 |                   30.5 |                       2 |                     0
             18753 |                    151 |                35 |                   15.5 |                       2 |                     0
             18754 |                    151 |                35 |                   12.8 |                       2 |                     0
             18643 |                    151 |                35 |                   4.25 |                       2 |                     0
             18644 |                    151 |                35 |                  22.15 |                       2 |                     0
             18645 |                    151 |                35 |                   7.45 |                       2 |                     0
             18646 |                    151 |                35 |                    7.5 |                       2 |                     0
             18751 |                    151 |                34 |                  25.34 |                       5 |                     0
             18752 |                    151 |                34 |                  30.54 |                       5 |                     0
             18753 |                    151 |                34 |                  15.48 |                       5 |                     0
             18754 |                    151 |                34 |                  13.08 |                       5 |                     0
             18643 |                    151 |                34 |                    4.3 |                       5 |                     0
             18644 |                    151 |                34 |                  22.44 |                       5 |                     0
             18645 |                    151 |                34 |                   7.34 |                       5 |                     0
             18646 |                    151 |                34 |                   7.54 |                       5 |                     0
```

Comment: Hmm yea thinking into the future i would want to add date/times to track the times as you could get the same temperature in the middle of a summer night as a September day. The question was kinda more directed for the query.

Comment: . . I re-read the question and it made sense as written.  It is just a bit subtle, and sample data would help make it even clearer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. I've added some sample data, I only started logging some data so the data is only showing at two temperatures at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the nearest rows using:

```
select t.*
from temperatures t
order by abs(temperature_value - ACTUAL_TEMPERATURE) asc
limit 2
```

Or, a better idea in this case, is `union`:

```
(select t.*
 from temperatures t
 where temperature_value <= ACTUAL_TEMPERATURE
 order by temperature_value desc
 limit 1
) union
(select t.*
 from temperatures t
 where temperature_value >= ACTUAL_TEMPERATURE
 order by temperature_value asc
 limit 1
)
```

This version is better because it returns only one row if the temperature is in the table.  This is a case where the `UNION` and duplicate removal is useful.

Next use conditional aggregation to get the information needed.  This uses a short-cut, assuming that the kw increases with temperature:

```
select min(temperature_value) as mintv, max(temperature_value) as maxtv,
       min(temperature_current_kw) as minck, max(temperature_current_kw) as maxck
from ((select t.*
       from temperatures t
       where temperature_value <= ACTUAL_TEMPERATURE
       order by temperature_value desc
       limit 1
      ) union
      (select t.*
       from temperatures t
       where temperature_value >= ACTUAL_TEMPERATURE
       order by temperature_value asc
       limit 1
      ) 
     ) t;
```

Finally, do some arithmetic to get the weighted average:

```
select (case when maxtv = mintv then minkw
             else minkw + (ACTUAL_TEMPERATURE - mintv) * ((maxkw - minkw) / (maxtv - mintv))
        end)
from (select min(temperature_value) as mintv, max(temperature_value) as maxtv,
             min(temperature_current_kw) as minkw, max(temperature_current_kw) as maxkw
      from ((select t.*
             from temperatures t
             where temperature_value <= ACTUAL_TEMPERATURE
             order by temperature_value desc
             limit 1
            ) union
            (select t.*
             from temperatures t
             where temperature_value >= ACTUAL_TEMPERATURE
             order by temperature_value asc
             limit 1
            ) 
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks really great. Ill take some time to review it and understand it but from a quick read it looks like what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Gordon. The code works great when it needs to find a new value, but I am getting a `division by 0` error when the row is already in the table. I believe this is because `(maxtv - mintv)` is giving 0 because both values are being set to the same value. I removed the first line and replaced it with `select * ...` and the result is the one row. Is there a way to avoid the calculation if there is only 1 row returned and it just returns the kW value?

Comment: @EricG . . . That is easy enough to fix with a `case` statement.  I thought just getting one row back would be a convenience, but it would cause that error.

Comment: Would `case when maxtv != mintv end` work? That would go just in front of the first from statement?

Comment: @EricG . . . Either way.  The two methods are equivalent.